# No internet connection after I upgraded to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I tried the fix someone listed for previous post but it did not work for me.  Please help!!!  Spent 2 hours on the phone with Microsoft but they could not fix it and told me tier 2 techs will charge me $100.  I cannot afford this.  Does anyone else know how to fix this problem, please.

Comment: Do you have compatible network adapter drivers installed ? Are you getting valid IP ?

Comment: Unfortunately you are talking to a 65 yr old woman....if you tell me where to find the information you ask, I will provide it.  I appreciate any help.  Thanks

Comment: It says driver software is up to date.  I know internet works because I am chatting from my Ipad wifi.

Comment: Can [find out the ip address](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/find-windows-10-device-ip-address/) ?

Comment: In the search window (that's the little circular icon at bottom left that says "ask me anything") type Network. Don't press return -- just give the search a little time to populate. Then click on the line that says "Find and fix networking and connection problems." That will take you to a repair wizard. See if that helps.

Comment: +1 for asking this on SuperUser. You go grandma'! :)

Comment: Hi, could you please open command line (press `Win+R`, enter `cmd` and confirm with `Enter` key). Run command `ipconfig /all`, copy the whole output (by selecting with mouse and pressing `Enter`) and share it with us.